# Flask WTF-forms adding select and textarea

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make a flask form which produces the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="title" class="field">
<textarea class="field"></textarea>
<select name="status">
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

So far, since I am new to python, I got this far.

```
  {% from "forms/macros.html" import render_field %}
  <form method="POST" action="." class="form">
  {{ render_field(form.title, class="input text") }}
```

My question is, have I got this correct so far for the title field, and assuming I have, could someone please explain how I can get a textarea and selectfield? I have read the docs and I am finding it almost impossible to get my head around it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to define the form not in the template but in the controller.
Example form definition :

```
class CommentForm(Form):
    language = SelectField(u'What You Want', choices=CAN_BE_FILLED_LATER_ON)
    code     = TextAreaField()
```

All you need later on is to -

1. Initialize the form by:

   ```
   comment_form = CommentForm()
   ```
2. Passing it to the template:

   ```
   return render_template('post_show.jinja2.html', comment_form=comment_form)
   ```
3. Render the form in the template:

   ```
   <div class="form-group" id='cg-{{comment_form.email.id}}'>
      {{comment_form.email.label(class='col-lg-2 control-label',for=comment_form.email.id)}} 
      <div class="col-lg-9"> 
        {{comment_form.email(class='form-control')}} 
        <span class="help-block" id='hl-{{comment_form.email.id}}'></span> 
      </div> 
   </div
   ```